# unable to get value of hidden input in jquery using find function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want when user click delete icon i need value of hidden input inside "delete" class but i am getting undefined can someone guide me where i am doing wrong

```
<table class="items-list">
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>Product name</th>
              <th>Product price</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            <!--Item-->
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="thumb"><a href="shop-single-item-v1.html"><img src="img/catalog/shopping-cart-thumb_2.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum"/></a></td>
              <td class="name"><a href="shop-single-item-v1.html">Wristlet</a></td>
              <td class="price">715,00 $</td>
              <td class="qnt-count">
                <a class="incr-btn" href="#">-</a>
                <input class="quantity form-control" type="text" value="2">
                <a class="incr-btn" href="#">+</a>
              </td>
              <td class="total">2715,00 $</td>
              <td class="delete"> <input type="hidden" name="row_id" value="123" > <i class="icon-delete"></i></td>
          </tr>

          </table>
```

my jquery code is as follow

```
$(document).on('click', '.shopping-cart .delete', function(){
       var $target = $(this).parent().find('.row_id').val();
       alert($target);

});
```

every time i run to alert i get error " undefined.tried many different ways but didnt work

Comment: `find('.row_id')` is looking for `class` named `row_id`. Dot `.` represents class

Comment: try `find('input[name="row_id"]')`

Comment: i tried with out . but it gives the same error .can u tell me how to do it correctly

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks dude. your solutions worked for me

Comment: @Umeriqbal You're very welcome, hope you understand the reason why your code didnt work

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yeah i got it now.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a class on the input, just a name, change your markup like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="row_id" class="row_id" value="123">
```

or your selector like this:

```
var $target = $(this).parent().find('input[name="row_id"]').val();
```

Comment: @Umeriqbal  `.shopping-cart` is not available in your code anywhere (element with this class name)

Comment: i only include the table that too with one row .there are mutiple rows in it. shopping cart class is somewhere down in page

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
       var $target = $(this).find('input').val();
       alert($target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="items-list">
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>Product name</th>
              <th>Product price</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th>action</th>
            </tr>
            <!--Item-->
            <tr class="item">
                <td class="thumb"><a href="shop-single-item-v1.html"><img src="img/catalog/shopping-cart-thumb_2.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum"/></a></td>
              <td class="name"><a href="shop-single-item-v1.html">Wristlet</a></td>
              <td class="price">715,00 $</td>
              <td class="qnt-count">
                <a class="incr-btn" href="#">-</a>
                <input class="quantity form-control" type="text" value="2">
                <a class="incr-btn" href="#">+</a>
              </td>
              <td class="total">2715,00 $</td>
              <td class="delete"> <input type="hidden" name="row_id" value="123" > <i class="icon-delete">Delete</i></td>
          </tr>

          </table>
```

Please check the Working Code.

I have firstly added a new `<TH>`  Tag to display the delete button.
And then in jquery i user **.find** to get the internal element of `<TD>` and as per your code it alters the value of hidden box

Thanks wish it might help you